# How does $\frac{5x}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{5}{2}x^{1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I don't understand the algebra behind how this equation equals true.

$\frac{5x}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{5}{2}x^{1/2}$

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L1oq.jpg)

**What I know about this problem**

I know $\sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}$
and I understand that 5/2 can be factored out,

but I don't understand how $\frac{x}{x^{1/2}} = x^{1/2}$

**what I am asking**

I am asking for someone to explain the logic behind the algebra or show a simpler version so I will understand the idea of the problem.

Comment: What you have written is not correct because of the lack of parentheses.  $5x/2x^1/2$ should strictly be read as $((((5x)/2)x^1)/2)=\frac{5x^2}4$ because the power binds most strongly, then you do the multiplication and division left to right.  Clearly that is not what you meant.  Parentheses, please.

Comment: Please try to learn $\LaTeX$ at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference so that we can understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the standard laws of powers is that $\frac {a^b}{a^c}=a^{b-c}$.  It is like adding exponents when you multiply $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$.  Exponents in the denominator are negative.

Comment: thank you, i knew that just couldn't think of an answer in the context of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=x^{1/2}\cdot x^{1/2}\implies x^{1/2}=x/x^{1/2}, \quad \text{if}\ x>0.$$